# Column that show the title of an item and point to a lookup value?

Tags: web-part, xslt-list-view-web-part, view

I have two lists, let's say "Parent" and "Child". There is a lookup in "child" list that point to "parent".

In a custom view of Child list, I'd like to have the title of "Child" display, with a link to a custom page with the Parent ID in the url.

In the custom XSL of my child view, I have written :

```
<a href="{$ServerRelativeUrl}/Pages/myPage.aspx?MyID={substring-before(@Parent., string( ';'))}" title="Open parent">
    Open Parent
</a>
```

This is not working as expected, the myId argument is empty.

If I write instead :

```
<a href="{$ServerRelativeUrl}/Pages/myPage.aspx?MyID={@Parent.}" title="Open parent">
    Open Parent
</a>
```

MyID equals `1;#1`, the value in SPFieldLookupValue form.

How can I properly extract the remote ID to build a link?

PS: I choose to use Xslt View webpart only for this purpose. If there is a better alternative solution do not hesitate to let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd just break it down a bit and do the substring-before operation before using it to look at why your substring is going wrong.

```
<xsl:variable name="myId" select="substring-before(@Parent., ';')" />
Parent: <b><xsl:value-of select="@Parent."/></b><br />
myId: <b><xsl:value-of select="$myId"/></b><br />
<a href="{$ServerRelativeUrl}/Pages/myPage.aspx?MyID={$myId}" title="Open parent">
    Open Parent
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, this help to see that there was an issue with my xsl. `@Parent.` was null, so I suppose I put my code in the wrong xsl template. To find the correct place, I use SPD, select CEll and start changing the content. This place was the correct place to put my customisation.